# redirect to a protected page after login (passport-local - express - nodejs)

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I am trying to show a protected page `/enquete` (a page that can only be seen by logged in users) after the `/login`. I am implementing it using [passport-local](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local). I have checked the login function returns a user (`req.isAuthorized()` is true) and it is actually trying to go to `/enquete` but when trying to access`/enquete` somehow the `req.isAuthorized()` is false. So I cannot access it :(.

I wonder what I am missing here? Is this the right way to do this?

These are parts of my code:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function (username, password, done) {
    process.nextTick(function() {
        model.findByUsername(username, function(err, user) {
            if (err) { return done(err); }
            if (!user) { return done(null, false, { message: 'Unknown user ' + username }); }
            if (user.password != password) { return done(null, false, { message: 'Invalid password' }); }
            return done(null, user); // <<-- I pass this so login was OK
        });
    });
}));

...

var app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(less(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({ secret: '123', resave: true, saveUninitialized: true }));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(flash({ locals: 'flash' }));


...

app.post(
    '/login',
    passport.authenticate(
        'local',
        { successRedirect: '/enquete', // <--- Please read below note on this
          failureRedirect: '/login' }));

function ensureLocalAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) { return next(); }
    res.redirect('/login');
}

app.get(
    '/enquete',
    ensureLocalAuthenticated,
    function(req, res) {
        res.render('pages/enquete');
    });
```

**Note:**
I have debugged `passport.authenticate` to make sure the login indeed succeeds. Since I am providing `successRedirect` option then `return res.redirect(options.successRedirect);` happens near `node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:245`. I have checked `req.isAuthorized()` is indeed true prior the redirect.

However in `ensureLocalAuthenticated` `req.isAuthorized` is false. Why?!

I am lost. Any help is appreciated

Comment: The only odd thing I see here is in your ensureLocalAuthenticated function, if the request is authenticated you call next(). That will execute the next middleware, but that function call originated in the middleware you want to be in.  Could next() be jumping over the rest of the logic in that route?

Comment: I thought so too at the beginning. I took that function from passport-local examples: https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/blob/master/examples/login/app.js#L154-157

Comment: Maybe try to say if (!req.isAuthenticated()) {res.redirect('/login')} and leave it at that. When the request is authenticated, the function will just return and continue in the route.

Comment: If the caller of the route is something like `return verify(req, res, next);` will it work? I think in this case `next` will be never called. Or I am missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly but it makes sense. I found that the reason was the order of the middleware were wrong! (facepalm). Changing the code to this made my server work as expected.

```
var app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(less(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(session({ secret: '123', resave: true, saveUninitialized: true }));
app.use(flash({ locals: 'flash' }));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```